# Deploy a runtime loaded plugin with dependency to a dll – where to put that dll?

Tags: windows, dll

We are building an audio plugin that can be loaded by a various number of audio production softwares. To make it as compatible as possible to all common softwares, we actually build three versions of it (Steinberg VST2 format, Steinberg VST3 format, Avid AAX format), which is achieved by wrapping our core plugin code with wrappers for those three APIs. All three versions are installed in the standard location as specified for each format.

Our plugin now depends on the Microsoft onnxruntime, which we want to dynamically link against. Now, what is the right way of deploying and handling this dependency? As the plugin is loaded by the users host software of choice at runtime, placing the dll dependency next to the executable is no option, since we don't know which host software the user will use and which of the three plugin formats this software will chose.

Being a macOS developer, I'm unfamiliar with Windows best practice here.

Ideally we would like to install the dll into a custom location. But this would need us to modify the systems PATH variable to ensure that the dll is found for all users when a host loads one of our plugins, right? I'm not sure if this is a clean solution?

Another option could be to install the dll into C:\Windows\System32 but my research revealed that there is no versioning information on the dlls located there, so in case some other application installed onnxruntime there as well (or if it's a never windows installation that already ships with onnxruntime), how could we ensure that its version is equal or greater than the version needed by our plugin (in which case we wouldn't overwrite it) or below our minimum needed version (in which would replace it)? This generally seems like bad practice as well to me.

So what's common best practice on Windows for such scenarios? Am I overlooking a proper solution?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/about-private-assemblies-

Comment: Thanks for the link! Still I'm not really sure how all this works – would you mind to briefly outline how Private Assemblies can be used in the context explained above?